# unity multiplayer components not there

Tags: unity, multiplayer

I just learned quite a bit about how to set up a multiplayer system in unity using it's built in scripts.  However, when I try to add a network manager to an empty, the search comes up empty! also when i click **add component** there is no tab for **network**.  What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unity is deprecating all old multiplayer development tools and wants developers to dont use them on new projects. if still want them you need to roll back to previous versions.

new api can be found in here:
https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/multiplayer

Comment: how different is the new system going to be?  Am I going to have to re-learn it?

Comment: @Millard its a little bit harder than solutions like photon and you will have much more responsiblity and you have to learn about multiplayer smoothing and synching algorithm but you have much freedom to make your own ideas

Comment: @Millard for start git documentation is enough

Comment: So it's harder than photon? I don't get why they would do that, the old one seemed great, I liked that it required little work on your part.

Comment: @Millard photon still there as photon is not a unity plugin and is well suported in unity but for more freedom unity wants to use new approach

Comment: "@Millard photon still there as photon is not a unity plugin and is well suported in unity but for more freedom unity wants to use new approach – virtouso 1 hour ago"  Do you mean that photon is a unity plugin, and is supported by unity?

Comment: Where do I find it, the Unit Asset Store?  I found it there, and started to import it, but it didn't just have the Photon Network, it had a massive amount of other stuff, like demos.  Is there a way I can just get the Network components?

Comment: Ok, I have found out that the system I have been learning was Unet, and it is in the package manager of Unity 2019.